# function json_populate_record(..., text) does not exist

Tags: postgresql-9.3

I went by the example from the [docu](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html) which went fine:

```
select * from json_populate_record(null::x, '{"a":1,"b":2}')
```

But my self-constructed JSON simplified similar to this did not work :-(

```
-- p_some_num of type int
select * from json_populate_record( null:my_record_type, '{"a":'||p_some_num||'',"b":2}' )
```

resulting in:

```
ERROR: function json_populate_record(my_record_type, text) does not exist
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I should have read more carefully and was not aware of the **implicit `text` to `json` conversion in the example**. After some fiddling around with what was wrong, of course the following works:

```
select * from json_populate_record( 
  null:my_record_type, ('{"a":'||p_some_num||'',"b":2}')::json )
```

Comment: what are you using for `my_record_type` in this example?

Comment: @Ryan Tuck: something like `CREATE TYPE x(a int,b int)` (as Pavan stated)

Comment: why can't postgres derive the types by itself? Like pandas does when reading csv files

Comment: @SergeyZaitsev it maybe could, but its open source and this is maybe not a widely used functionality and thus priority. pg is way behind oracle or m$ in some areas since decades. but it is robust and feature-rich enough to be a fitting competitor in many use cases.

Comment: @SergeyZaitsev you can use tables, views or custom types as valid types. Unfortunately unable to make completely dynamic tables from JSONB though.

Answer (score 3):

Andreas Dietrich answered your question, I'll be a little more specific with the example.
You can find the answer over
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17905501/postgresql-insert-data-into-table-from-json/17908760#17908760).

According to the documentation, the base or record type is referred from either a Type or a Table. Using which it can determine the column mapping.

Type is a user defined data type. You can find about a Type construct [here](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-user-defined-data-types/).

**tldr;**

for that to work, you have create a table like this.

```
CREATE TABLE x(a int,b int);
```

or a type like this.

```
CREATE TYPE x(a int,b int);
```

Then run the query.

```
select * from json_populate_record(null::x, '{"a":1,"b":2}')
```